# i want set default sort in angular js manage with icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new in angular js. i already set sorting . when i set dafault setting that time my sorting arrow visible . i want to like default sorting with mange my icon. please help me on this. thanks in advance .

```
   <table style="border: 1px solid " class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>


                        <th ng-click="orderByField='JackpotAmount'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="link">
                            <a href="">
                                JackPot Amount <span ng-show="orderByField == 'JackpotAmount'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span ng-show="reverseSort" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
                            </a>

                        <th ng-click="orderByField='StartDate';  reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="link">
                            <a href="">
                                Start Date <span ng-show="orderByField == 'StartDate'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span ng-show="reverseSort" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
                            </a>


                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="orderByField='EndDate'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="link">
                            <a href="">
                                End Date <span ng-show="orderByField == 'EndDate'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span ng-show="reverseSort"     class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
                            </a>


                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="jackpots1 in listjackpot|orderBy:sort:reverseSort">

                        <td>{{ jackpots1.JackpotAmount }}</td>
                        <td>{{ jackpots1.StartDate  }}</td>
                        <td>{{ jackpots1.EndDate }}</td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

below is my controller

```
    $scope.orderByField = 'StartDate';
    $scope.reverseSort = true;
```

Comment: Please explain what " i want to like default sorting with mange my icon" means.  I don't really get what you want to do, you're description isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The orderBy argument is the wrong variable name.

```
orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort
```

Instead of

```
orderBy:sort:reverseSort
```

Comment: i want sorting after click otherwise i dont want any sorting. i want my table data as same in database.

like my table data is

Comment: but is showing like this
   jackpotamount   start date  end date
     90000             01/04/2014   02/12/2014
     10000            01/02/2014   02/02/2014
     60000             0/03/2014    02/20/2014